# I wrote a code to show the availability of doctors according to the date, but when the field on mysql is empty i have this array error

Tags: php, arrays

This is the code i'm talking about

```
session_start();

include ('configg.php');

$query = "SELECT Date, Time FROM gp_appointment WHERE Name = '$_POST[doctor]' AND Date = '$_POST[date]'";

$result = mysql_query($query);


  $data = array();

  while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
     $data[] = $row;

  }

 $colNames = array_keys(reset($data))


 ?>

 <table border="1">
 <tr>
    <?php

       //print the header
       foreach((array)$colNames as $colName)
       {
          echo "<th>$colName</th>";
       }

    ?>
 </tr>

    <?php

       //print the rows
       foreach((array)$data as $row)
       {
          echo "<tr>";
          foreach($colNames as $colName)
          {
             echo "<td>".$row[$colName]."</td>";
          }
          echo "</tr>";
       }


    ?>
 </table>
 <a href="homepage.php">Go back to the homepage</a><br>
 <a href="docname.php">Check another doctor</a><br>
```

When i chose a date that exist in the databse all works fine, but if a choose a date not-existent i recieve this error:

> Warning: array_keys() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given
>   in H:\Project\xampplite\htdocs\example\phptutorial\doctorav.php on
>   line 15

Somebody know what to do?

Comment: As it says, array_keys recieves a boolean. See the documentation of reset

Comment: possible duplicate of [mysql\_fetch\_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in select](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2973202/mysql-fetch-array-expects-parameter-1-to-be-resource-boolean-given-in-select)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if you get data than only perform any operation. Or just print message `No Records Found`.

```
if((!empty($data)){
     // Perform all operation
}
else{
   echo "No records Found";
}
```

**Note:** [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/). They are no longer maintained [and are officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). See the [**red box**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-connect.php)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo), or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers).

Comment: Why would you use `count` and the implicit fact that 0 is equivalent to false when you can use `empty` ?

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in H:\Project\xampplite\htdocs\example\phptutorial\doctorav.php on line 15 I have this error when i do that

Comment: I solved actually, there was a un.needed ( that i didn't see in your code thanks!

Answer (score -1):

You need to check if the results are empty first before processing them.

```
if($data){
    $colNames = array_keys(reset($data));
}
```

You probably also need to check this in the output as well, or else the for-each will fail as well :)

Comment: If i do this i recieve this error Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in H:\Project\xampplite\htdocs\example\phptutorial\doctorav.php on line 15